# Prove that limsup and liminf of an independent sequence are independent of finite number of terms

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf, independence

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be an independent sequence of random variables on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

What I'm trying to prove is:

Prove that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ is independent of $\liminf X_n$.

I've seen a proof of it already, but it was complicated. I am trying to prove it in another way.

This seems that this can be almost immediately just from the [definition/s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282308/limsup-liminf-of-a-random-variable) and can be extended to limsup and to any finite collection of the random variables of the sequence.

Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281014/140308), I guess:

$\liminf X_n = \sup_{n \geq 1} \inf_{m \geq n} \ X_m = \sup_{n \geq k+1} \inf_{m \geq n} \ X_m$

I'm not quite sure how to say this precisely, but I think such shows that $\liminf X_n$ has nothing to do with $X_1, ..., X_k$.  Perhaps we say something like $\sigma(\liminf X_n) \subseteq \sigma(X_{k+1}, X_{k+2}, ...)$, which is independent of $X_1, ..., X_k$  ?

Similarly, I guess that $\limsup X_n = \inf_{n \geq 1} \sup_{m \geq n} \ X_m = \inf_{n \geq k+1} \sup_{m \geq n} \ X_m$ and $\sigma(\limsup X_n) \subseteq \sigma(X_{k+1}, X_{k+2}, ...)$, which is independent of $X_1, ..., X_k$.

Extending to proving $\{X_k\}_{k \in K}$,where K is finite and $K \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, is independent of $\limsup X_n$ or $\liminf X_n$:

Pick the highest index , call it k* and then

$\liminf X_n = \sup_{n \geq 1} \inf_{m \geq n} \ X_m = \sup_{n \geq k^{*}+1} \inf_{m \geq n} \ X_m$

Pls do not present a different kind of proof if what I am attempting is wrong. Pls just state what is wrong with my attempt.

Comment: It seems correct to me. But could you please rephrase this as a question? (it is how mse works)

Comment: @Siméon 'I'm not quite sure how to say this precisely. Perhaps we say something like σ(lim infXn)⊆σ(Xk+1,Xk+2,...), which is independent of X1,...,Xk ?' ?

Comment: @Siméon Oh wait. I excluded something important. Will edit.

Comment: @Siméon Edited 8th paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can make your idea rigorous.

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$ be a sequence of independent real random variables. Let us fix some integer $k$ and let
$$
\mathcal F = \sigma(X_m ; m \leq k), \qquad \mathcal G = \sigma(X_m ; m \geq k+1).
$$
For all $n \geq k+1$, the random variable $Y_n = \sup_{m \geq n} X_m$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable. Since a limit of $\mathcal G$-measurable functions is still $\mathcal G$-measurable, the random variable $\lim_{n\to \infty} Y_n = \limsup_{n\to\infty} X_n$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable.

The random variables $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are $\mathcal F$-measurable, and the random variable $\limsup X_n$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable. They are therefore independent since the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are independent $\because X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$ are independent. In particular, the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are independent of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}  X_n$.

Comment: Thanks Siméon! How is the edit?

Comment: @BCLC: Your edit was alright, but I prefer the current version.